# how to declare Iterator for set of stacks in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stack, set

I am creating a class that is a set of stacks. I want to use an iterator to get the element at the end and access its functions. But I get the following error

```
setOfStacks.cpp:40:6: error: expected ';' after expression
            set< stack<Type> >::iterator it = mSetOfStacks.end();
               ^
               ;
```

The class works with a template and is declared like this

```
template<typename Type>
class SetOfStacks 
{
public: 
        SetOfStacks(int capacityPerStack);
    void            push(Type object);
    Type            pop();
    bool            isEmpty();
private:
    void            createNewStackWithElem(Type object);
private:

        int                 mStackCapacity;
        set<stack<Type> >   mSetOfStacks;
};
```

Then in my insert function I try to get the stack at the end

```
set< stack<Type> >::iterator it = mSetOfStacks.end();
if( *it->size() < mStackCapacity )
    *it->push(object);
```

which is where I get the error when trying to declare the iterator
setOfStacks.cpp:40:6: error: expected ';' after expression

also, I tried

```
set<stack<Type> >::iterator it = mSetOfStacks.end();
```

but it did not work either

The entire push function

```
template<typename Type>
void SetOfStacks<Type>::push(Type object) {
    // if entire set is empty make a new stack
    if( mSetOfStacks.empty() ) {
        stack<Type> newStack;
        newStack.push(object);

        mSetOfStacks.insert(newStack);
    }
    else {
        // check if current stack within limits
        set< stack<Type> >::iterator it = mSetOfStacks.end();
        if( *it->size() < mStackCapacity )
            *it->push(object);
        else {
            // duplicate code, make another function
            stack<Type> newStack;
            newStack.push(object);

            mSetOfStacks.insert(newStack);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a **lot** wrong with your code, but this particular error doesn't seem to match. Can you post slightly more contextual code?

Comment: Can you please post the entire insert function.

Comment: I attached the entire function

Comment: Please also note, that `end()` will return an iterator **past** the end of the set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a function template the nested name `iterator` is a dependent name which is considered to be an object rather than a type. You want to indicate that `iterator` is a type using the `typename` keyword:

```
typename std::set<std::stack<Type> >::iterator it = mSetOfStacks.end();
// ^-- here
```

Templates are parsed in two stages: during the first phase the code is parsed for its logical components without any knowledge of template arguments or entities depending on the template arguments could look like. If there is a nested name depending on a template argument the compiler assumes this this name is an object rather than a type unless you explicitly state that it is a type using the `typename` keyword.

Comment: I also have run into another problem. after getting the value of my iterator I try to access the stack functions but when I try to push a value I get an error in my insert function

`code
typename set< stack<Type> >::iterator it = mSetOfStacks.end();
  --it;
  if( it->size() < mStackCapacity ) {
   it->push(object);
  } else {
`

member function 'push' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >', but function is not marked const
                        it->push(object);

Comment: @SakibShaikh: you can't change the key of a `std::set<...>`, of course! That would mess up its internal invariants. It seems you rather want something like `std::list<...>`.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is the perfect keyword for this :

```
auto it = mSetOfStacks.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

When using C++11, you don't need to specify the iterator type to define an iterator when initializing it from something like `mSetOfStacks.end()`. You can use `auto` instead:

```
auto it = mSetOfStacks.end();
```

Also, you should not access this iterator, since it points *one element past the end*. If you want the last element in the set, decrement the iterator before accessing it:

```
--it;
// then use *it
```

or refer to the last set by using a reference variable:

```
auto & lastSet = *(--it);
// then use lastSet instead of *it
```

If your compiler doesn't support `auto`, use Dietmar's solution.